# Android Studio 0.5.2 Gradle Refresh Project failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**UPDATED WITH MY EVENT LOG**

**LAST EDIT**
After trying out every possible solution i could find i've come to a fresh install of Windows. Doing this i noticed that this was indeeed a **firewall** issue, my antivirus was blocking the `studio64.exe process.`

I have freshly installed Android Studio 0.4.2 then immediately updated to 0.5.2 without opening or creating any new projects.

I updated the Android SDK then created a new project. I keep getting the error with the Gradle Refresh Failed even though i tried to change the local gradle distribution, nothing seems to work, everything i try Gradle replies with: "Please fix your Gradle configuration"...

This had happened to me since i updated to Android studio 5.1, never before.

I tried with Gradle 1.10 and 1.11 and the Gradle wrapper included in the install kit downloadable from the website http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Here are my gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And the outside build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Now i've tried downloading the latest version from the Canary Build and then downloading the SDK sepparately, still the same issue, this is really annoying... is there any network setting i might be having setup incorrectly?

Currently i am using the default grale wrapper from Android Studio, and this is the error i get:

```
10:58:37 AM Gradle 'ClujTourist' project refresh failed:
            A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
            : Gradle settings
```

After trying to compile the project with:  `gradlew.bat --stacktrace assemble`

this is what i got:

```
C:\Users\Adrian-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\ClujTourist>gradlew.bat --stacktrace as
semble

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ClujTourist'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11
.+.
     Required by:
         :ClujTourist:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring roo
t project 'ClujTourist'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigu
rationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:507)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:82)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all depe
ndencies for configuration ':classpath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfigurat
ion.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfigura
tion.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyR
esolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDepend
encyResolver.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDep
endencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingA
rtifactDependencyResolver.java:176)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:465)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateCla
ssPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:75)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:145)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.eva
luate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundExc
eption: Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0
.11.+.
Required by:
    :ClujTourist:unspecified
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependenc
yToModuleResolver$DynamicVersionResolveResult.notFound(LazyDependencyToModuleRes
olver.java:170)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependenc
yToModuleResolver$AbstractVersionResolveResult.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleRes
olver.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependenc
yToModuleResolver.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.VersionForcingDependency
ToModuleResolver.resolve(VersionForcingDependencyToModuleResolver.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.Dependency
GraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolveModuleRevisionId(Dependenc
yGraphBuilder.java:935)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.Dependency
GraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:
296)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.Dependency
GraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.Dependency
GraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDep
endencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDep
endencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager
.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDep
endencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDepe
ndencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDepe
ndencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc
ess.java:148)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(De
faultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManag
er.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDepe
ndencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyR
esolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigs
ArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyRes
olver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDep
endencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationReso
lver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration
$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
        ... 36 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.864 secs

C:\Users\Adrian-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\ClujTourist>
```

Also tried to delete the .gradle and gradle files from my project. Nothing seems to work.

**EDIT** What seems to be working for me so far is replacing the service directory `.gradle` to your root directory as it seems there might have been a path problem to that directory. Let me know if this solved it for you!

Comment: Just a nit, it is 0.5.1, not 5.1, big difference.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: replacing the service directory .gradle worked for me thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy fix!

The `defaultConfig` part of your `build.gradle` file needs to go inside `buildTypes`, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"


    buildTypes {
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

See the guide for [Migrating from 0.8 to 0.9](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09).

Furthermore, make sure you're using the up-to-date Gradle distribution url (if you're using the Gradle wrapper).

In your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file should be the following line:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

Finally make sure you `clean` your project before building again (Build -> Clean Project).

Comment: To reiterate -- creating a new project and re-importing WILL work.  Judging by the comments on Maziar's answer, it seems you've already done this.  However, this should be marked as the correct answer (IMO) while his should upvoted for being helfpul.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your kind suggestions. Maziar's answer was definitely helpful but only until i powered down my computer, got home and re-opened it only to find the same error...

I've tried out your fix, modified my gradle files and indeed this seems to b building OK while running: `gradle assembleDebug` in a command line where my project is. I have added the JAVA_HOME and the  grdale bin path to my system variables. But when i try to run with Android Studio i get the same error....

Comment: Something must be indeed wrongly set up with my gradle configuration

Comment: And as a sidenote: Now not even the trick with the new project is no longer working

Comment: I looked a little further at your posted Stacktrace, specifically the following line: `Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11`.  Updated my answer with another suggestion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Btw, this stuff totally sucks to deal with.  Lemme know if my updated solution helps -- happy to investigate further if it doesn't.

Comment: Is there another place in your project where you're setting the `classpath` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'`?  It should be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'`

Comment: It's 0.9.+ everywhere now... this is getting really annoying, if I don't find a solution fast enough i might be forced to go back to Eclipse ADT which is too bad because i really liked Android Studio...

Comment: Are you depending on any `jar`s in `libs`?

Comment: it's a plain new project created upon a fresh install of Android Studio

Comment: did you see my edit? I edited your answer but it seems like it didn't got approved

Comment: Yeah it was apparently rejected by some moderators (not me).  Sorry, not sure what was going on there.  Seems like there's something wrong with the IDE configuration.  Did you try uninstalling / reinstalling Android Studio?  Should reset all your defaults.

Comment: I still haven't found a proper solution, i am thinking to refresh my PC (Windows 8.1) and that shall uninstall any preferences i might have setup wrongly. However your interest in answering to my question makes me award you the bounty, thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have tried these two solutions above, but neither could solve the problem, **finally I shut down my AVAST safety software...then It worked！** gradle sync is ok..
Although I don't know why, but shutting down AVAST did solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem.

To solve that just create another project in Android Studio 0.5.2 and after that when **new project completely Created and Built close it and open your old project** (project '**ClujTourist**' ). Now you can build ClueTourist successfully.

Please let me know if anything goes wrong.

Comment: I cannot believe this is actually working... Thank you so much, i will however let the question open for the next 2 days, if no other explanation will com up i will award you the bounty. So far this is a working solution, hopefully it will not fail again after 2 days:) Thanks for now.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for you :) .. I hope you success.

Comment: What do you know, this also failed... I cannot understand how can this be working only until I reboot my pc...

Comment: =)) this is my question two, because this solution just worked fine for me after several restarts. I don't know how this situation has happened for you. anyway thanks for polite and kind response.