# android gradle error with compile - Error:Artifact

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have some problem.
2 days ago I write app on android developer tools, compile and install on phone, all ok - all worked.
But now I want to compile it - don't can, error log

```
Error:Artifact 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0:support-annotations.jar' not found.
Gradle 'test51' project refresh failed
```

why??? I nothing changed, don't opened project don't enabled notebook.

how I can fixed it? please help.

Comment: How have you mentioned this artifact? groupid:artifactid:x.x.x ? or it has an extra :artifactname.jar as well. Do you see this artiact in the repository (binary repo like artifactory/nexus etc).

Comment: I update with android sdk manager, but don't help. :(

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437097/android-studio-0-5-2-gradle-refresh-project-failed

Comment: what is a tools I can use for export android app from android developer tools  for android eclipse?