# how to solve this gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.2.

[image]

Comment: post your app level and project level build.gradle file

Comment: when can i get app level file i am new to android development

Answer (score 1):

Set 2.3.2 instead of 2.4.2 and sync

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended

> You should use latest gradle version.

please update your gradle with all uses library than problem would be solved.

For More Helps You Can view this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437097/android-studio-0-5-2-gradle-refresh-project-failed?rq=1). Otherwise upload your gradle file image

Comment: i have upgraded my gradle to latest version

Comment: View This Problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437097/android-studio-0-5-2-gradle-refresh-project-failed?rq=1

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sdsmdg.harjot.MusicDNA"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 36
        versionName "1.2.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

Answer (score -1):

Post your  build.gradle file of app